# Что означает эта конструкция с EventHandler?

Tags: c#, события, делегаты, handlers

VS предложил "упростить"

```
...
EventHandler<MyEventArgs> args = MyHandler
if (args != null)
{
    args(this, e);
}
...
```

На

```
...
MyHandler?.Invoke(this, e)
...
```

Что это значит? Куда копать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В С# 6 появился так называемый null propagation operator. Он позволяет упростить довольно утомительные проверки на null, и означает, что если выражение в его левой части равно null, то он вернёт null, а если оно имеет какое-то другое значение, то будет возвращено значение поля/свойства из правой части, либо будет выполнен метод из правой части. Согласитесь, что писать

```
data = some?.GetData();
```

явно удобнее, чем

```
if(some != null)
    data = some.GetData();
```

Comment: более того - эта конструкция потокобезопасна

Answer (score 3):

Данная конструкция

```
MyHandler?.Invoke(this, e);
```

логически эквивалентна следующей

```
if ( MyHandler != null ) MyHandler.Invoke(this, e);
```

Такую же конструкцию ввели для оператора индексирования. Например

```
int[] a = null;
int? x = a?[0];

a = new int[1] { 10 };
int? b = a?[0];
```

Это средство появилось в новой версии C# 6.0

Comment: Выражение `MyHandler` должно вычисляться только один раз, а у Вас оно вычисляется дважды когда условие `MyHandler != null` истинно.

Comment: @PetSerAl Вот поэтому и ввели такую конструкцию.:)

Answer (score 1):

> Ключевое слово `null` является литералом, представляющим пустую ссылку, которая не ссылается ни на один объект.  `null` является значением по умолчанию переменных типа ссылок.

Для ключевого слова `null` определены специальные операторы:

- `int? a;`
  Разрешаем использование `null` для `value type`. Вместо `int` можно указать любой тип значения.
- `obj?.SomeMethod();`
  Проверяем объект `obj` на `null` и, если объект не равен `null`, обращаемся к члену типа.
  Также помимо `?.` можно обращаться к индексатору `?[]`.
- `int y = x ?? -1;`
  Проверяем если `x != null`, берем его значение, иначе выполняем конструкцию справа от `??`, в данном случае устанавливаем `y = -1`.

Также можно комбинировать между собой:

```
int? length = customers?.Length ?? -1; // если customers != null, вернуть customers.Length, иначе вернуть -1
```